# rreplace - How to replace the last occurrence of an expression in a string?

Tags: python, string

Is there a quick way in Python to replace strings but, instead of starting from the beginning as `replace` does, starting from the end? For example:

```
>>> def rreplace(old, new, occurrence)
>>>     ... # Code to replace the last occurrences of old by new

>>> '<div><div>Hello</div></div>'.rreplace('</div>','</bad>',1)
>>> '<div><div>Hello</div></bad>'
```

Comment: Good question, judging by the complicated solutions to such a simple problem.

Comment: There is an elegant one-liner in the answers below that took 9 years(!) to get added to this question, simply scroll down to find it.

Answer (score 261, accepted):

```
>>> def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
...  li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
...  return new.join(li)
... 
>>> s
'1232425'
>>> rreplace(s, '2', ' ', 2)
'123 4 5'
>>> rreplace(s, '2', ' ', 3)
'1 3 4 5'
>>> rreplace(s, '2', ' ', 4)
'1 3 4 5'
>>> rreplace(s, '2', ' ', 0)
'1232425'
```

Comment: Very nice! In an unscientific benchmark of replacing the last occurrence of an expression in a typical string in my program (> 500 characters), your solution was three times faster than Alex's solution and four times faster than Mark's solution. Thanks to all for your answers!

Comment: Thanks, it works. The [`.replace`](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace) method takes a third optional argument 'count' which tells it to replace the first n occurrences. Would it not have been intuitive if that would take a -1 like but unfortunately it won't, so we need your solution.

Answer (score 94):

Here is a **one-liner**:

```
result = new.join(s.rsplit(old, maxreplace))
```

> Return a copy of string *s* with all occurrences of substring *old* replaced by *new*. The first *maxreplace* occurrences are replaced.

and a full **example** of this in use:

```
s = 'mississipi'
old = 'iss'
new = 'XXX'
maxreplace = 1

result = new.join(s.rsplit(old, maxreplace))
>>> result
'missXXXipi'
```

Comment: Nice! Used it to remove trailing commas from lines: `line = "".join(line.rsplit(",", 1))` while keeping padding space afterwards.

Comment: what can be modified in here to use it on a dataframe column?

Answer (score 25):

I'm not going to pretend that this is the most efficient way of doing it, but it's a simple way. It reverses all the strings in question, performs an ordinary replacement using `str.replace` on the reversed strings, then reverses the result back the right way round:

```
>>> def rreplace(s, old, new, count):
...     return (s[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], count))[::-1]
...
>>> rreplace('<div><div>Hello</div></div>', '</div>', '</bad>', 1)
'<div><div>Hello</div></bad>'
```

Answer (score 17):

Just reverse the string, replace first occurrence and reverse it again:

```
mystr = "Remove last occurrence of a BAD word. This is a last BAD word."

removal = "BAD"
reverse_removal = removal[::-1]

replacement = "GOOD"
reverse_replacement = replacement[::-1]

newstr = mystr[::-1].replace(reverse_removal, reverse_replacement, 1)[::-1]
print ("mystr:", mystr)
print ("newstr:", newstr)
```

Output:

```
mystr: Remove last occurence of a BAD word. This is a last BAD word.
newstr: Remove last occurence of a BAD word. This is a last GOOD word.
```

Comment: when i use this, the format of digital book page never changed whereas using 'join' fuction changed the format. great!

Answer (score 5):

If you know that the 'old' string does not contain any special characters you can do it with a regex:

```
In [44]: s = '<div><div>Hello</div></div>'

In [45]: import re

In [46]: re.sub(r'(.*)</div>', r'\1</bad>', s)
Out[46]: '<div><div>Hello</div></bad>'
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive solution to the problem:

```
def rreplace(s, old, new, occurence = 1):

    if occurence == 0:
        return s

    left, found, right = s.rpartition(old)

    if found == "":
        return right
    else:
        return rreplace(left, old, new, occurence - 1) + new + right
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
def replace_last(string, old, new):
    old_idx = string.rfind(old)
    return string[:old_idx] + new + string[old_idx+len(old):]
```

Similarly you can replace first occurrence by replacing ***string.rfind()*** with ***string.find()***.

I hope it helps.

Comment: + for not reversing potentially large string.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a list of strings you can use list comprehension and string slicing in a one liner to cover the whole list.. No need to use a function;

```
myList = [x[::-1].replace('<div>'[::-1],'<bad>'[::-1],1)[::-1] if x.endswith('<div>') else x for x in myList]
```

I use **if** **else** to keep the items in the list that don't meet the criteria for replacement otherwise your list would just be the items that do meet the criteria.