# Right-to-left string replace in Python?

Tags: python, string

I want to do a string replace in Python, but only do the first instance going from right to left. In an ideal world I'd have:

```
myStr = "mississippi"
print myStr.rreplace("iss","XXX",1)

> missXXXippi
```

What's the best way of doing this, given that `rreplace` doesn't exist?

Comment: rel: http://stackoverflow.com/q/2556108/989121

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rreplace - How to replace the last occurrence of an expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/rreplace-how-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-an-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 116, accepted):

`rsplit` and `join` could be used to simulate the effects of an `rreplace`

```
>>> 'XXX'.join('mississippi'.rsplit('iss', 1))
'missXXXippi'
```

Comment: +1 for a solution that's readily understandable by programers that follow.

Comment: As opposed to other solutions, this one is also easily extensible to execute multiple replacements from the right.

Comment: If you want to replace known extension or just remove/append something from/to end you can do it even simpler `yourFilepath.rsplit('.py', 1)[0] + '.log'` :)

Comment: I wonder why didn't python teams write a specific method to replace strings from right to left?

Comment: @jave.web or starting with 3.9 `yourFilepath.removesuffix('.py') + '.log'`

Answer (score 27):

```
>>> myStr[::-1].replace("iss"[::-1], "XXX"[::-1], 1)[::-1]
'missXXXippi'
```

Comment: that is so *not* newbie friendly... :)

Comment: I'm assuming this does what @sleeplessnerd's does but without `reverse`?

Comment: Yeah, the .reverse() was a guess :) - But the concept is clear.

Comment: Please never ever use code like this in any code you share or expect others to read!

Answer (score 17):

```
>>> re.sub(r'(.*)iss',r'\1XXX',myStr)
'missXXXippi'
```

The regex engine cosumes all the string and then starts backtracking untill `iss` is found. Then it replaces the found string with the needed pattern.

---

**Some speed [tests](http://ideone.com/xdQKh)**

The solution with `[::-1]` turns out to be faster.

The solution with `re` was only faster for long strings (longer than 1 million symbols).

Comment: Is this more efficient than the reversal method for short strings (<20 chars)?

Comment: @TomMedley I don't know. I didn't do any speed tests. As I know, backtracking is quite slow. And if `iss` is somewhere in the beginning of the string, it'll take quite a while to bracktrack until the engine finds a position where `iss` matches.

Comment: @TomMedley But I don't think that those `[::-1]` in the other solutions are faster :)

Comment: It's always the last few chars of the string actually

Comment: @TomMedley If I were concerned with the speed issues, I would test all the solutions with `timeit` module.

Comment: @TomMedley - this `re` solution is in this special case about 9 times slower than mine with `[::-1]` (12.6µs vs 1.36µs).

Comment: @eumiro Yeah. I thought that it may be connected with regexp compilation. But it turned out to be more slow even if used with precompiled pattern.

Comment: For short strings you really, really shouldn't be worrying about speed! The regexp solution is faster to write, read and debug (for anyone familiar with regular expressions). It is also the more general approach, since you can use it with more complex replacements. Unless your code will be doing millions of string edits per minute, the regexp is by far the better solution.

Answer (score 16):

you may reverse a string like so:

```
myStr[::-1]
```

to replace just add the `.replace`:

```
print myStr[::-1].replace("iss","XXX",1)
```

however now your string is backwards, so re-reverse it:

```
myStr[::-1].replace("iss","XXX",1)[::-1]
```

and you're done.
If your replace strings are static just reverse them in file to reduce overhead. 
If not, the same trick will work.

```
myStr[::-1].replace("iss"[::-1],"XXX"[::-1],1)[::-1]
```

Comment: you forgot to reverse the matched text and the replacement text

Comment: Nope, I said at the end what to do if you wanted them reversed.

Comment: Upvoted for a clever alternative solution!

Answer (score 3):

```
def rreplace(s, old, new):
    try:
        place = s.rindex(old)
        return ''.join((s[:place],new,s[place+len(old):]))
    except ValueError:
        return s
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use [`str.rpartition()`](https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/str/rpartition.html) which splits the string by the specified separator from right and returns a tuple:

```
myStr = "mississippi"

first, sep, last = myStr.rpartition('iss')
print(first + 'XXX' + last)
# missXXXippi
```

Answer (score 0):

Using the package *fishhook* (available through pip), you can add this functionality.

```
from fishhook import hook

@hook(str)
def rreplace(self, old, new, count=-1):
    return self[::-1].replace(old[::-1], new[::-1], count)[::-1]

print('abxycdxyef'.rreplace('xy', '--', count=1))

# 'abxycd--ef'
```

Answer (score -1):

It's kind of a dirty hack, but you could reverse the string and replace with also reversed strings.

```
"mississippi".reverse().replace('iss'.reverse(), 'XXX'.reverse(),1).reverse()
```

Comment: There's no `reverse()` method for strings.