# How to string.replace once starting from the right? -python

Tags: python, regex

How to string.replace once starting from the right?

I could do it from the left.

```
>>> x = 'foo bar bar'
>>> x.replace(' ', ' X ', 1)
'foo X bar bar'
```

Or with `re.sub`:

```
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(' ', ' X ', x, 1)
'foo X bar bar'
```

From the right, i could do:

```
>>> x = 'foo bar bar'
>>> x[::-1].replace(' ', ' X ', 1)[::-1]
'foo bar X bar'
```

But is there any other way to replace once starting from the right?

Comment: What's wrong with the approach you are using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, I think you're approach is ok. Oneliner, pretty pythonic.

The question suggested in the comments ([Right-to-left string replace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python?lq=1)) provide several useful answers that worth measuring them.

One is the same approach you're taking: `x[::-1].replace(' ', ' X ', 1)[::-1]` and the other one is with `rsplit` and `join`.

I profiled both and this was the output I got:

```
$python -mtimeit -s "s = 'foo bar bar'" "s[::-1].replace(' ', ' X ', 1)[::-1]"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 1.18 usec per loop

$python -mtimeit -s "s = 'foo bar bar'" "' X '.join(s.rsplit(' ',1))"
1000000 loops, best of 3: 0.8 usec per loop
```

So my recommendation is the second approach which seems a lot faster. That being said, whichever you chose, put a comment beside telling `# this is right replacing!` because either way is pretty unclear what the code does :)

Hope this helps!