# python str.replace() with borders

Tags: python, string, replace

I'm trying to use the function  `str.replace(",", ";"[, count])` but when i fill in count (let's say 1) it only changes the first `","` but i want to change a certain "," (working with boundries)` does anyone have a idea on how to do this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right-to-left string replace in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python)

Comment: It's unclear if you want to change all of them, just the last, or certain one? Maybe show a better example.

Comment: @I'L'I I'm sorry i was a bit unclear, i need to change a certain on (working with boundry)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `rsplit` and join:

```
s = "foo,foobar,foo"

print(";".join(s.rsplit(",",1)))
```

Or reverse the string, replace and reverse again:

```
print(s[::-1].replace(";",",",1)[::-1])
```

splitting actually seems a little faster:

```
In [7]: timeit s[::-1].replace(";",",",1)[::-1]
1000000 loops, best of 3: 521 ns per loop

In [8]: timeit ";".join(s.rsplit(",",1))
1000000 loops, best of 3: 416 ns per loop
```

If you want to change the ith occurrence:

```
def change_ith(st, ith, sep, rep):
    return "".join([s + rep if i == ith else s + sep
                    for i, s in enumerate(st.split(sep, ith), 1)]).rstrip(sep)
```

Output:

```
In [15]: s = "foo,foo,bar,foo,foo"

In [16]: change_ith(s, 1, ",",";")
Out[16]: 'foo;foo,bar,foo,foo'

In [17]: change_ith(s, 2, ",",";")
Out[17]: 'foo,foo;bar,foo,foo'

In [18]: change_ith(s, 3, ",",";")
Out[18]: 'foo,foo,bar;foo,foo'

In [19]: change_ith(s, 4, ",",";")
Out[19]: 'foo,foo,bar,foo;foo'
```

There are cases where join will could give incorrect output if you had a string ending in the sep and a few other edge cases, to  get a more robust function we would need to use a regex passing a lambda as the repl arg and using `itertools.count` to count how many matches we got:

```
import re
from itertools import count
def change_ith(st, ith, sep, rep):
    return re.sub(sep, lambda m, c=count(1): rep if next(c) == ith else m.group(0), st)
```

Or applying the same logic to join:

```
from itertools import count
def change_ith(st, ith, sep, rep):
    cn = count(1)
    return  "".join([rep if ch == sep and next(cn) == ith else ch 
                   for ch in st])
```

Comment: Thanks for that tip but is it also possible to change a middel ","? (with a boundry or something?)

Comment: @Lode, for more complex patterns you would probably use a regex, it would be possible without but a bit ugly

Comment: @lode, no worries, I added a couple of more robust options incuding a regex approach

Comment: This was for a school project so i don't think imports are allowed but thanks for the answer

Answer (score 0):

You should reverse, replace, and reverse again. I use reverse indexing for that in the example below:

```
s = "one, two, three, four, five"

print str.replace(s[::-1], ',', ';', 1)[::-1]
```