# Input two files with same name but different extension

Tags: python, file

I want to input two files with same name but different extension by doing the input of just one:

```
tkMessageBox.showinfo(title="Info",message="Please input both the .rwh file")

# the filetype mask (default is all files)
mask = \
[("files","*.rwh"),
 ("All files","*.*")]

title = 'Open'                
files = askopenfilenames(initialdir=self.initial_dir, filetypes=mask,title=title)
```

Then the part that I do not how to do. It has to create a file object by reading the file input and then by reading the name create another one with same name but different extension (.row).

Afterwards I call a function which uses both files object.

The files have different extension because they contain different information, both files are in the same folder.

Answer (score 3):

[**`os.path.splitext`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.splitext) allows you to get the root name:

```
>>> import os

>>> filename = '/my/filename.rwh'
>>> root, ext = os.path.splitext(filename)
>>> root
'/my/filename'

>> root + '.row'
'/my/filename.row'
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming you already know one file name, for example:

```
file = 'test.rwh'
```

then you simply could [`replace`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) it with `.row`, the other file extension:

```
file.replace('.rwh','.row')
```

this gives `test.row`. In the case of having multiple `.rwh` values you can use Peter Wood's comments or use for example regular expressions:

```
import re
file = 'test.rwh.rwh'
re.sub('.rwh$','.row',file)
```

returns `test.rwh.row`.

Comment: It's possible that the filename could have `.rwh` in other positions than at the end.

Comment: See [Right-to-left string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python), particularly [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9943875/1084416).

Answer (score 0):

Convert the file name to a string and use `str.join()` to add the file endings.

This should work unless the file endings differ from case to case.