# Replace left most comma with two characters

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to change `a,b,c to a,b=>c`
but after finding the last comma index using `rfind`, how should I replace the `,` with `=>` ？

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Right-to-left string replace in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python)

Answer (score 4):

```
a = "a,b,c"

'=>'.join(a.rsplit(',',1))

Output:- 'a,b=>c'
```