# Replace last 2 occurrence of specific word in file using python

Tags: python

I'm opening file and searching for specific word to replace the last 2 occurrence of that word in a file.

I have opened file and try to replace but it is replacing first 2 occurrence. where as i want to replace last two occurence

```
s = open("mount.txt").read()
s = s.replace('mickey', 'minnie',2)
f = open("mount.txt", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

This is text is just for example. Actual text is different.

```
#mount.txt# 

I'm mickey. minnie is my friend.
mickey is the good name given by my parents.
mickey loves to play cricket.
Where as his parents doesn't like Mickey's habit.



#Replaces text[mount.txt]#

I'm mickey. minnie is my friend.
Mickey is the good name given by my parents.
minnie loves to play cricket.
Where as his parents doesn't like minnie's habit.
```

Comment: you want to replace last 5 occurrence or last 3 occurrence or last 2 occurrence?

Comment: Check this solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943504/right-to-left-string-replace-in-python

Comment: @LucasWieloch Last two occurence but of a file not a string.

Comment: @PRUTHVIBENPATEL Your code leaves the first file open; it never gets properly closed. I suggest using `with open() as f` to avoid that; see my answer for an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
s = open("mount.txt").read()
sr = s.rsplit('mickey', 2)
s = 'minnie'.join(sr)
f = open("mount.txt", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible solution. Note: this version is case sensitive, so `mickey` and `Mickey` are NOT treated as the same; but if you need case insensitive replacements this code will at least point you in a possible direction to a complete solution.

```
def func(word_to_search, replacement_word, num_replacements):
    with open('test.txt') as f:
        old_lines = f.readlines()

    new_lines = []
    counter = 0
    for line in reversed(old_lines):            # iterate in reverse order
        if counter < num_replacements:
            # only check if 'num_replacements' has not been reached yet

            while word_to_search in line:
                line = line.replace(word_to_search, replacement_word, 1)
                counter += 1

                if counter >= num_replacements:
                    # exit while loop because 'num_replacements' has been reached
                    break

        new_lines.append(line)

    # reverse list again to get original order
    new_lines = list(reversed(new_lines))

    with open('test2.txt', 'w') as f:
        f.writelines(new_lines)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    func(
        word_to_search='mickey',
        replacement_word='MINNIE',
        num_replacements=2)
```

The input:

```
I'm mickey. minnie is my friend.
mickey is the good name given by my parents.
mickey loves to play cricket.
Where as his parents doesn't like Mickey's habit.
```

The output (`Mickey` on the last line was not replaced because it is not all lowercase):

```
I'm mickey. minnie is my friend.
MINNIE is the good name given by my parents.
MINNIE loves to play cricket.
Where as his parents doesn't like Mickey's habit.
```