# Finding last occurrence of substring in string, replacing that

Tags: python, string, parsing

So I have a long list of strings in the same format, and I want to find the last "." character in each one, and replace it with ". - ". I've tried using rfind, but I can't seem to utilize it properly to do this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [rreplace - How to replace the last occurrence of an expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/rreplace-how-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-an-expression-in-a-string)

Answer (score 168, accepted):

This should do it

```
old_string = "this is going to have a full stop. some written sstuff!"
k = old_string.rfind(".")
new_string = old_string[:k] + ". - " + old_string[k+1:]
```

Comment: Thanks so much man. Going to have to study that for a minute... this is utilizing slices, right?

Comment: @AdamMagyar yes, container[a:b] slices from a up to b-1 index of the container. If 'a' is omitted, then it defaults to 0; if 'b' is omitted it defaults to len(container). The plus operator just concatenates. The rfind function as you pointed out returns the index around which the replacement operation should take place.

Answer (score 28):

To replace from the right:

```
def replace_right(source, target, replacement, replacements=None):
    return replacement.join(source.rsplit(target, replacements))
```

In use:

```
>>> replace_right("asd.asd.asd.", ".", ". -", 1)
'asd.asd.asd. -'
```

Comment: I definitely like this solution but having `replacements=None` parameter seems like an error to me because if the parameter is omitted the function will give an error (tried in Python 2.7). I would suggest either remove the default value, set it to -1 (for unlimited replacements) or better make it `replacements=1` (which I think should be the default behaviour for this particular function according to what the OP wants). According to the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split) this parameter is optional, but it must be an int if given.

Comment: In case anyone wants a one-liner for this: `". -".join("asd.asd.asd.".rsplit(".", 1))`.  All you're doing is performing a string split from the right side for 1 occurrence and joining the string again using the replacement.

Answer (score 15):

I would use a regex:

```
import re
new_list = [re.sub(r"\.(?=[^.]*$)", r". - ", s) for s in old_list]
```

Comment: This is the only answer that works if there's no dot at all. I'd use a lookahead though: `\.(?=[^.]*$)`

Answer (score 6):

A one liner would be :

`str=str[::-1].replace(".",".-",1)[::-1]`

Comment: **This is wrong**. You're reversing the string, replacing it and then reversing it back. You're doing `.replace` on a reversed string. Both of the strings passed to `replace` have to be reversed too. Otherwise when you reverse the string a second time the letters you just inserted will be backwards. 

You can only use this if you're replacing one letter with one letter, and even then I wouldn't put this in your code incase someone has to change it in the future and starts wondering why a word is written sdrawkcab.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the function below which replaces the first occurrence of the word from right.

```
def replace_from_right(text: str, original_text: str, new_text: str) -> str:
    """ Replace first occurrence of original_text by new_text. """
    return text[::-1].replace(original_text[::-1], new_text[::-1], 1)[::-1]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = "A long string with a . in the middle ending with ."
```

#   if you want to find the index of the last occurrence of any string, In our case we #will find the index of the last occurrence of with

```
index = a.rfind("with")
```

# the result will be 44, as index starts from 0.

Answer (score -1):

Naïve approach:

```
a = "A long string with a . in the middle ending with ."
fchar = '.'
rchar = '. -'
a[::-1].replace(fchar, rchar[::-1], 1)[::-1]

Out[2]: 'A long string with a . in the middle ending with . -'
```

---

Aditya Sihag's answer with a single `rfind`:

```
pos = a.rfind('.')
a[:pos] + '. -' + a[pos+1:]
```

Comment: This reverses the replacement string too. Other than that, it's a repeat of root's answer, and, as I say there, pretty inefficient.

Comment: @Lattyware You mean it reverses `a`?

Comment: I mean it reverses `'. -'` in the output.

Comment: Just expecting the user to reverse the string literal by hand isn't a great idea - it is prone to mistakes and unclear.

Comment: @Lattyware Agreed. I've made it a var. (I realise it's an inefficient method, and is not suitable in all cases - your `replace_right` is much nicer)

Comment: It's not mine - I just edited the example on Varinder Singh's answer - my first thought was actually this method as well.