# Python: strip characters line by line from subprocess.Popen

Tags: python, subprocess, string-formatting, stdout

Trying to strip characters out of output from the following snippit: `subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=true,stdout=subprocess.PIPE)`

Longterm i need to split the output into seperate list indexes. Trying to test this with stdout output to validate that its working first. Here is a snippit of the code right now:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.4

import subprocess

def writefile():
  sites = ['blue.com', 'red.com']               
  for site in sites:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["python dnstwist.py -g " + site + "| sed -e '1,8d' | grep -v -"],shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,universal_newlines=True)
    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      if line!= '':
        print(line.strip('/'))
      else: 
        break
```

I have also tried:

```
      line = proc.stdout.readline().strip('/')
      if line!= '':
        print(line)
      else: 
        break
```

output always looks like this sample.  Notice the forwardslash is not being stripped out:

```
Replacement     4ed.com    212.48.70.37/United Kingdom MX:mail.4ed.com

Replacement     r4d.com    69.172.201.208/United States
```

Also it looks like its adding \n or \r.

Longterm i would like it to be something i can parse out to look like the following:

`{'4ed.com': ['Replacement', '212.48.70.37', 'somewhoisdata', 'United Kingdom'] }`

...etc

Comment: try using `strip()` not `rstrip()`

Comment: note that rstrip only takes away the characters in your argument (in this case, "/") if it is trailing, not all the occurrences of the character in the string

Comment: and strip is for both trailing and leading

Comment: Just tried strip and had the same results. the output still contains "/" 
    while True:
      line = proc.stdout.readline()
      if line!= '':
        print(line.strip('/'))

Comment: use `replace('/', '')`.

Comment: as suggested by @RNar, ff the replacement text you've included is correct you should be using `replace('/', '')` instead of `strip()`. If you want to replace only the last occurence of `/` then try what is suggested [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14496006/finding-last-occurence-of-substring-in-string-replacing-that)

Comment: you don't need `shell=True` here: `sed` and `grep` parts could be done in Python easily. Here's how to [read output from a subprocess line by line](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279). Consider [importing the python module and calling the corresponding function (perhaps using  `multiprocessing`) instead of spawning a subprocess and processing its output](http://stackoverflow.com/q/30076185/4279)