# Python: replace terms in a string except for the last

Tags: python, string, replace

How does one go about replacing terms in a string - except for the last, which needs to be replaced to something different?

An example:

```
    letters = 'a;b;c;d'
```

needs to be changed to

```
    letters = 'a, b, c & d'
```

I have used the replace function, as below:

```
    letters = letters.replace(';',', ')
```

to give

```
    letters = 'a, b, c, d'
```

The problem is that I do not know how to replace the last comma from this into an ampersand. A position dependent function cannot be used as there could be any number of letters e.g 'a;b' or 'a;b;c;d;e;f;g' . I have searched through stackoverflow and the python tutorials, but cannot find a function to just replace the last found term, can anyone help?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/how-to-replace-the-last-occurence-of-an-expression-in-a-string

Answer (score 17, accepted):

In `str.replace` you can also pass an optional 3rd argument(`count`) which is used to handle the number of replacements being done.

```
In [20]: strs = 'a;b;c;d'

In [21]: count = strs.count(";") - 1

In [22]: strs = strs.replace(';', ', ', count).replace(';', ' & ')

In [24]: strs
Out[24]: 'a, b, c & d'
```

Help on `str.replace`:

```
S.replace(old, new[, count]) -> string

Return a copy of string S with all occurrences of substring
old replaced by new.  If the optional argument count is
given, only the first count occurrences are replaced.
```

Comment: Gave this a try and it works perfectly, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4):

```
letters = 'a;b;c;d'
lettersOut = ' & '.join(letters.replace(';', ', ').rsplit(', ', 1))
print(lettersOut)
```

Answer (score 3):

Another way of doing it in one line without knowing the number of occurrences:

```
letters = 'a;b;c;d'
letters[::-1].replace(';', ' & ', 1)[::-1].replace(';', ', ')
```