# How to remove exclamation marks from a sentence except the last one

Tags: python, python-2.7

Hi I guess that the title says it all.

For example if I have a string like: `"The food! is great!!!"`

I want python to change it to: `"The food is great!"`

Thank you all in advance. :)

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself yet? Where did you get stuck?

Comment: does your string always end in !? are there always 4?

Comment: @depperm   No it does not always end in ! and the number of ! is random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a regex with lookahead:

```
import re

re.sub(r'!+(?=.*\!)','',text)
```

The regex

```
!+(?=.*\!)
```

matches any sequences of exclamation marks given the lookahead `(?=.*\!)` sees an exclamation mark. All these exclamation marks are `sub`stituted by the empty string.

```
$ python2
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 19 2016, 06:48:10) 
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import re
>>> text="The food! is great!!!"
>>> re.sub(r'!+(?=.*\!)','',text)
'The food is great!'
```

Comment: i think this is a bit too advanced for the OP and anyone who would lookup such a thing

Comment: advanced yes, but it is a valid solution

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: well personally I think regexes are very elegant tools because you *specify* what you want and do not have to worry (much) about how it works behind the curtains. Furthermore that's in my opinion not a reason for a dv: it is functionally correct and the answer explains what is happening.

Comment: Furthermore if later the OP changes their mind and wants to tweak the specifications a bit, he/she should probably not return to this site for another question. Regexes are a common tool and there is plenty of documentation on it.

Comment: I did not downvote and i find the answer a very fine one. Putting my self in OP's shoes though, I probably wouldn't even read it in fear of its complexity.

Answer (score 2):

```
strs="The food! is great!!!"
count=strs.count("!")-1
strs = strs.replace('!','',count)
print strs
```

https://stackoverflow.com/a/16268024/6626530

output

```
The food is great!
```

Comment: Why do you do the last replacement?

Comment: @Willem Van Onsem you are right , last replacement is not required, updated it

Comment: @Shijo you are also removing the exclamation mark in the middle.

Comment: @Ev.Kounis: that is the intended behavior as you can see in the example the OP gave.

Comment: @ Steven Rumbalski ,Yes, the question is "How to remove exclamation marks from a sentence except the last one", so it keeps the last one

Answer (score -2):

replace all '!' in the string with ''. then string = string + '!'

```
string.replace('!','')
string = string + '!'
```

Comment: Works only if his string ends with !

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge What do you mean? This is actually a smart solution

Comment: If  his string doesn't end with !, then a ! is appended that shouldn't be there. How is that smart? Also the only ! may be in the middle...

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge this is a detail that can be taken care of with an `if`-statement though. The idea is smart

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge The exclamation mark in the middle is indeed a problem. Didn't see that. You are right.

Comment: @JacquesdeHooge: `s = s.replace('!', '') + ('!' if s.endswith('!') else '')`  This assumes the text contains only once sentence.  Works fine for `'Who said!!!! that?'` and `'No Way!!!!!'`.

Comment: Does that work for 'Who said!!!! that?'? Doesn't give you 'Who said that?'?