# How to replace all occurences except the first one?

Tags: python, python-3.x, replace, find-occurrences

How to replace all the repeated words except the first one in the string? That is these strings

```
s='cat WORD dog WORD mouse WORD'
s1='cat1 WORD dog1 WORD'
```

will be replaced to

```
s='cat WORD dog REPLACED mouse REPLACED'
s1='cat1 WORD dog1 REPLACED'
```

I can't [replace the string backward](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2556108/3416774) because I don't know how many time the word occurs on each line. I do figure out a circuitous way:

```
temp=s.replace('WORD','XXX',1)
temp1=temp.replace('WORD','REPLACED')
ss=temp1.replace('XXX','WORD')
```

But I want a more pythonic method. Do you have any idea?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use a `string.count` together with the `rreplace`

```
>>> def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
...     li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
...     return new.join(li)
... 
>>> a
'cat word dog word mouse word'
>>> rreplace(a, 'word', 'xxx', a.count('word') - 1)
'cat word dog xxx mouse xxx'
```

Comment: thanks for that. However, `word` is actually a set of words, and I use a dictionary to replace them, e.g. `for i,j in dic.items(): line = rreplace(line,i,j,line.count(i)-1)`. This doesn't work

Comment: Please add the complete code, input, output.  And what exactly `don't work`?