# How to remove some dots from a string in python

Tags: python-3.x

I'm extracting an int from a table but amazingly comes as a string with multiple full stops.
This is what I get:

```
p = '23.4565.90'
```

I would like to remove the last dots but retain the first one when converting to an in.
If i do

```
print (p.replace('.',''))
```

all dot are removed
How can I do this.

N/B
Tried a long way of doing this

```
p = '88.909.90000.0'
pp = p.replace('.','')
ppp = list(''.join(pp))
ppp.insert(2, '.')
print (''.join(ppp))
```

BUT 
discovered that some figures come as 
e.g. 170.53609.45
and with this example, I'll end up with 17.05360945 instead of 170.5360945

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here is a solution:

```py
p = '23.4565.90'

def rreplace(string: str, find: str, replace: str, n_occurences: int) -> str:
    """
    Given a `string`, `find` and `replace` the first `n_occurences`
    found from the right of the string.
    """
    temp = string.rsplit(find, n_occurences)
    return replace.join(temp)

d = rreplace(string=p, find='.', replace='', n_occurences=p.count('.') - 1)

print(d)

>>> 23.456590
```

Credit to [How to replace all occurences except the first one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32422509/8150685).

Answer (score 5):

What about `str.partition`?

```
p = '23.4565.90'
a, b, c = p.partition('.')
print(a + b + c.replace('.', ''))
```

This would print:
`23.456590`

EDIT: the method is `partition` not `separate`

Comment: I tested with examples with multiple `.` and with no `.`. It seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

This isnt the best way in doing it especially if your not getting similar values but if you do some sort of loop to check how many values there are then do this it should work. but if you only have three dots in the string try this:

```
p = '88.909.90000.0'
p = p.split('.')
p = p[0] + '.' + p[1] + p[2]
```

then if you want it as a number do this
p = float(p)

Comment: You could `for` loop this solution for any number of `.`

Comment: Yes. Im working on that know ill update my answer once i've done that

Answer (score 0):

```py
def add_dots(to_add):
    res=""
    for letter in to_add:
        res= res + letter + "."
        print{:-1}res)
    
def remove_dots(to_remove): 
    print (to_remove):
    
add_dots("test")    
remove_dots("t.e.s.t.")
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.