# How to replace all occurrence of a string in file except the first occurrence using Python?

Tags: python-3.x

Here is the content of my file

[image]

I want to replace all occurrence of **pyt_batch_id** with any number but not the first occurrence.

I tried the below method and it is working as expected but I don't think this the best approach.

```
s = open("BATCH_ROLLBACK.txt").read()
s = s.replace('pyt_batch_id', '123456')
f = open("BATCH_ROLLBACK.txt", 'w')
f.write(s)
f.close()

f2 = open('BATCH_ROLLBACK.txt', 'r')
contents = f2.read().replace('123456', 'pyt_batch_id',1)
f2.close()
f2 = open('BATCH_ROLLBACK.txt', 'w')
f2.write(contents)
f2.close()
```

output :-

[image]

Could anyone please suggest other alternative methods?

Found similar question but that is for a line not for file.
[How to replace all occurences except the first one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422431/how-to-replace-all-occurences-except-the-first-one)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to replace all occurences except the first one?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32422431/how-to-replace-all-occurences-except-the-first-one)

Comment: @Adam.Er8 Before asking the question I have visited that page but that solution would not work with the file.