# Remove trailing and leading char using csv.reader

Tags: python, csv

How can I remove a certain char if my value in second column of csv starts with "(" or end with ")", I'm very new to python guys help me to solve this

**Example:**

```
0023632fa4a860be8bc85ddf39fc19c3c4c2e6fe,(Java Archive (JAR) 4049-0),Not Supported,
005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,(WIN32 EXE 7-2),Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,
```

to

```
0023632fa4a860be8bc85ddf39fc19c3c4c2e6fe,Java Archive (JAR) 4049-0,Not Supported,
005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,WIN32 EXE 7-2,Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,
```

I have this code using DATA INFILE

```
TRIM(TRAILING ')' FROM TRIM(LEADING '('
```

**How can I apply it here in my code:**

```
with open(fullPath, 'rb') as file:
     csv_data = csv.reader(file)
     next(csv_data)
```

Comment: Give a sample of how that line should be converted.

Comment: updated my question

Comment: why is `(`JAR`)` still present then?

Comment: because i only need to delete the () at the start and end of the string

Answer (score 2):

A solution using `lstrip()` and `rstrip()`

```
import csv

new_rows = []
with open('test.csv', 'rt') as file:
    csv_data = csv.reader(file, delimiter=',')
    for row in csv_data:
        new_rows.append([row[0],row[1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')'),row[2]])

print(new_rows) # Outputs ['0023632fa4a860be8bc85ddf39fc19c3c4c2e6fe,Java Archive (JAR) 4049-0Not Supported', '005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,WIN32 EXE 7-2ansom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027']
```

**Edit**

To save the edit on a new .csv file just add:

```
with open('test2.csv', 'wt') as file:
    writer = csv.writer(file)
    for row in new_rows:
        writer.writerow(row)
```

Comment: how can i line break this? itried new_rows.append(row[0]+','+row[1].lstrip('(').rstrip(')')+','+row[2] + "\n") so the array would be like the csv but it doesnt work

Comment: i need to break it using "\n" so when printing it will show per line

Comment: to get line per line just use: `for line in new_rows: print(line)`

Comment: is there anyway to save it to an updated csv? because im trying to import my csv to database

Comment: I have included the code to write the `new_rows` to a `test2.csv` file. If this has helped you please consider upvoting and accepting the answer. Thanks.

Comment: it is saving but when im opening it, it makes empty line per row and all the values are in the first column

Comment: this will of course depend on the way you import it in your .csv reader.

Comment: I have edited the code to save you trouble of this. Let me know if it works.

Comment: thanks, i will figure it out how to fix this, if i did it i will accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way of doing it, I've replaced the first occurrence and the last occurrence of '(' and ')' from the string. Hope it helps.

```
s = '''0023632fa4a860be8bc85ddf39fc19c3c4c2e6fe,(Java Archive (JAR) 4049-0),Not Supported,
005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,(WIN32 EXE 7-2),Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,'''

def last_replace(s, old, new, occurrence):
    '''Replaces the last occurence of the character'''
    li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
    return new.join(li)

new_string = [last_replace(line, ')', '', 1).replace('(', '', 1) for line in s.split('\n')]
print(new_string)
```

Output:

```
['0023632fa4a860be8bc85ddf39fc19c3c4c2e6fe,Java Archive (JAR) 4049-0,Not Supported,',
'005c41fc0f8580f51644493fcbaa0d2d468312c3,WIN32 EXE 7-2,Ransom.Win32.TRX.XXPE50FFF027,']
```

PS : I stole the `last_replace` function from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/rreplace-how-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-an-expression-in-a-string)

Comment: How about `line.lstrip('(').rstrip(')')`?

Comment: Yea that would work too, Went with this approach so it will be easy to replace multiple `(` , `)` later on.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great opportunity to learn about [regular expressions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression)! Regular expressions are a method for recognising and dealing with patterns in text. Python has a regular expressions package as part of its standard library. I'm going to assume you're using Python 3 for the rest of this answer, where the package is named `re`.

The TLDR answer to your question is:

```
import re

string_without_parens = re.sub(r'(^\()|(\)$)', '', string_maybe_has_parens)
```

What's going on here, though? the `re.sub()` function takes three parameters, a regular expression string (denoted by the leading `r`), a string that you want to replace each match with, and the string you want to substitute in. The regular expression here is `(^\()|(\)$)`. So what does that mean? Lets take it step by step:

- A set of parentheses `()` represents a capture group, these can be used to get the matches out, but I've used them as a way to group characters we're looking for together. There are two capture groups in this regular expression: `(^\()` and `(\)$)`.
- Between these is a `|` character, this represents OR in regular expression language, so it's looking for something that matches either `(^\()` *or* `(\)$)`.
- The first capture group `(^\()`: has two things inside it (well, three really, but we'll get to that). The first is `^`, this is what is called an *anchor*, this one in particular says, "only look at the start of the string". The second (and third) characters are `\(` which says "I want to look for an opening parentheses". Because parentheses are using in regular expressions, we have to use the backslash character to "escape" it.
- The second capture group `(\)$)`: contains an escaped closing parenthesis `\)` and other anchor. This anchor represents the end of the string, in the same way `^` represented the start.
- Together this says: "match an opening parentheses at the beginning or a closing parenthesis at the end", and the `re.sub()` function says replace anything that matches this pattern with '' (i.e. nothing).

Hope that helps! If you want to play more with regular expressions, you can try out [regexr](https://regexr.com/), which helped me wrap my head around them.

Comment: This will be inefficient if you only want to replace `(` and `)`

Comment: "Some people, when confronted with a problem, think 'I know, I'll use regular expressions.' Now they have two problems." - Jamie Zawinski

Comment: @VineethSai Regular expressions can be compiled to DFA that operate in O(n), and I suspect the use of the anchors would optimise this to O(1) under the hood. Your use of the `replace` method makes your solution O(n). Blanket statements of "regex is slow" don't really help anyone. I'd suggest giving this a read if you want to learn more about regex speed: https://swtch.com/~rsc/regexp/regexp1.html. Regex is also provides compact, comprehensible syntax (in this case a single line).