# convert string to timezone iso format in python

Tags: python, type-conversion, timezone

i'm trying to convert a string with this form `"2019-07-17T16:00:50.282203+01:30"` to timezone format so i can update `models.DateTimeField` field.

models.py:

```
from django.utils import timezone

class task(models.Model):
       title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
       create_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
       .
       .
       .
```

request will be like this:

```
{
    "title": "editeddd task",
    "create_date" : "2019-07-17T16:00:50.282203+01:30"

}
```

being stuck in converting UTC part.

view.py:

```
.
.
.
create_date = datetime.strptime(self.request.data['expiration_date'], '%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%f%z')
.
.
```

‍‍the error is for `%z` part. it can converting `"2019-07-17T16:00:50.282203+0130"` but not `"2019-07-17T16:00:50.282203+01:30"` (notice to `:` in UTC part)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are referencing `request.data`, it looks as though you are using Django REST Framework. In that case the most straightforward way is to use DRF's serializers to parse / validate the incoming data.

```py
from rest_framework import serializers

class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Task
        fields = ('title', 'create_date')
```

If you just want to retrieve the validated data you can do:

```py
>>> serializer = TaskSerializer(data=request.data)
>>> serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True)
>>> serializer.validated_data
OrderedDict([('title', 'editeddd task'), ('create_date', datetime.datetime(2019, 7, 17, 14, 30, 50, 282203, tzinfo=<UTC>))])
```

Or if you want to save a new task:

```py
task = serializer.save()
```

It's important to validate all incoming data and validating each field manually by reaching into `request.POST` or `request.data` tends to be error prone. DRF's serializers (or Django's forms) have a lot of pre-built logic and make the task significantly easier and safer.

Answer (score 1):

Being strict while sending and tolerant while receiving, you should do a little string mangling on that create_date string before passing it on to `strptime`.

My suggestions is to work with a regular expression, or to have look at [rreplace - How to replace the last occurrence of an expression in a string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2556108/rreplace-how-to-replace-the-last-occurrence-of-an-expression-in-a-string) to get rid of that last `:`.

Hope this helps!