# remove a point from text file - python

Tags: python

I need your help to write script python to remove last point in a text file.

I tried to remove a point from last sentence for first Without success.

```
f = open('text.txt','r')
last = f.readlines()
f.close()

f2 = open('text.txt','w')
last_line = last[-1:]
for i in range(0,(len(last)-1)):
if i == len(last)-1:
    f2.write(last[i].replace('.',' '))

f2.close
```

Comment: Please check the indentation of your code,  the indentation in your question seems incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

Using this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2556252/8564999), you can do like this

```
def rreplace(s, old, new, occurrence):
    li = s.rsplit(old, occurrence)
    return new.join(li)

f = open('text.txt','r')
content = f.read()
f.close()

f = open('text.txt','w')
f.write(rreplace(content, '.', ' ', 1))
f.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a one-liner from this [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59082116/14385360):

```
result = new_string.join(text.rsplit(old_string, how_often))
```

Which would be in your case:

```
def remove_last_point(text):
    return "".join(text.rsplit(".", 1))
```